# Redux or Pub/Sub?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a react app which will record audio.
When the user presses a button the component should cause it's parent to run a stopRecording() routine, resulting in saving the file and some json data about conditions and triggering a user flow.

I'd been looking into Redux which seems fine for JSON data but I'm less sure about audio files.
But does Redux fulfill the purpose of pub/sub for notifying components they should do stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But does Redux fulfill the purpose of pub/sub for notifying components
>   they should do stuff.

Yes. Whenever the store changes, all "connected" components will receive the new store update and consequently componentDidUpdate will get called. So for example, let's say that you would like to trigger an action and listen on that trigger, then you would do something like this:

The subscriber

```
class MyListenerComponent extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.triggerAction !== prevProps.triggerAction) {
      // do something meaningful here, perform user flow, stop recording, whatever
    }
  }
  ...
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return({
    triggerAction: state.triggerAction
  })
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyListenerComponent)
```

The action triggerer (publisher)

```
this.props.dispatch({type: 'TRIGGER_ACTION', triggerAction: 'some data here'})
```

The reducer:

```
switch(action.type) {
  case 'TRIGGER_ACTION':
  return ({
    ...state,
    triggerAction: action.triggerAction,
  })
}
```